# Node.js - How to return after all asynchronous calls have finished

Tags: javascript, node.js

As shown bellow, I am pushing the object `link_to_json` returns into an array `allShirts` declared in `html_to_json`.

However, the `console.dir` on the third last line and the return value of `html_to_json` logs an array of undefined references. Which I presume is because `console.dir` and `return` is executed before `link_to_json` functions finished.

How do I ensure the return value of `html_to_json` is a filled up `allShirts` array?

```
//Go to individual links and scrape relevant info
const link_to_json = (link) => {
    request(link, (err, res, body) => {
        if (!error_handler(err, res, link)) {
            const $ = cheerio.load(body);
            const shirt_detail = $('.shirt-details').find('h1').text();

            const Title = shirt_detail.substr(shirt_detail.indexOf(' ') + 1);
            const Price = shirt_detail.substr(0, shirt_detail.indexOf(' '));
            const ImageURL = $('.shirt-picture').find('img').attr('src');
            const URL = link;

            return new Shirt(Title, Price, ImageURL, URL);
        } else return {};
    });
}

//Crawl through all individual links listed in Root
const html_to_json = body => {
    const allShirts = [];
    const $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $('.products').find('a').each((index, val) => {
        allShirts.push(link_to_json(rootURL + $(val).attr('href')));
    });

    console.dir(allShirts); // <--- HERE
    return allShirts;
}
```

Comment: Is request the asynchronous method? I would say to use promise all.

Comment: I don't think `Promise.all()` prevents `html_to_json` from returning, it ensures `html_to_json` returns everything or nothing.

Comment: Yeah, but you could use .then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to go after this, but I like the [Async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) library for this sort of thing.

How I'd handle your problem is to actually get all the URLs first, so changing your body scrape to something like this instead:

```
const shirtLinks = [];
$('.products').find('a').each((index, val) => {
    shirtLinks.push(rootURL + $(val).attr('href'));
});
```

You need your conversion function to be asynchronous as well:

```
const linkToJSON = (link, cb) => {
    request(link, (err, res, body) => {
        if (!error_handler(err, res, link)) {
            const $ = cheerio.load(body);
            const shirt_detail = $('.shirt-details').find('h1').text();

            const Title = shirt_detail.substr(shirt_detail.indexOf(' ') + 1);
            const Price = shirt_detail.substr(0, shirt_detail.indexOf(' '));
            const ImageURL = $('.shirt-picture').find('img').attr('src');
            const URL = link;

            return cb(null, new Shirt(Title, Price, ImageURL, URL));
        }
        return cb();
    });
}
```

Then use async to map them across the async function that fetches the data:

```
async.map(shirtLinks, linkToJSON, (err, results) => {
    console.dir(results);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. I find it easier to debug this way.

```js
let getShirtDetailsBody = (link) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(link, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(body)
      }
    })
  })
}

let getShirt = (body) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  const shirt_detail = $('.shirt-details').find('h1').text();

  const Title = shirt_detail.substr(shirt_detail.indexOf(' ') + 1)
  const Price = shirt_detail.substr(0, shirt_detail.indexOf(' '))
  const ImageURL = $('.shirt-picture').find('img').attr('src')
  const URL = link

  return new Shirt(Title, Price, ImageURL, URL)
}

let getAllProductsShirtsBody = (body) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(body)
  
  return Promise.all($('.products').find('a').map((index, val) => {
    return getShirtDetailsBody(`rootURL${$(val).attr('href')}`)
  }))
}

getAllProductsShirtsBody(yourbody).then(allShirtsBody => {
  const allShirts = allShirtsBody.map(shirtBody => { return getShirt(shirtBody) })
  console.log(allShirts)
}).catch(err => { console.log(err) })
```